# Illegal offset type in isset or empty Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, log, system.log

I currently have some errors in my system.log that I can not solve, due to default Magento core files:

```
2018-07-31T08:55:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty  in /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 53
2018-07-31T08:55:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: addcslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given  in /lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 296
2018-07-31T08:55:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Illegal offset type  in /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 59
2018-07-31T08:55:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Illegal offset type  in /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 60
2018-07-31T08:55:56+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Illegal offset type  in /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Source/Table.php on line 62
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: try to disable all third party extension first, then check.

Comment: Any success on this one?